# Обезболивающий и обезбаливающий

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Что правильно, и что ошибочно? В речи слышны оба слова, второе — много чаще. В печати наоборот...

> Но вместо того чтобы обратиться к товарищам за помощью, он по ночам
> крадется с ключами к аптечке (отсюда звон) и принимает обезболивающее.
> [Сергей Ивашко. Долететь до Марса — не главное // «Детали мира», 2011]
>
> Врач возражал, потому что не понимал, что с больным, говорил, что
> обезболивающее может спровоцировать обострение. [А. Н. Бузулукский.
> Пальчиков // «Волга», 2014]

> Более того, в данном случае обезбаливающее относилось не иначе как к
> разряду опиатов: галлюцинаторный бред банковского бизнеса вызывал у
> его субъектов эйфорическую веру в себя и при любом на себя покушении
> рождал фрустрационное неудовольствие, обозначаемое торчками
> словосочетанием «ломать кайф». [Александр Гаррос, Алексей Евдокимов.
> [Голово]ломка (2001)]
>
> Страшно болела голова, обезбаливающее уже не помогало. [Ирина
> Евгеньева. Прокуратура выясняет, почему погибла пациентка Фонда «Город
> без наркотиков» // Комсомольская правда, 2012.06.18]

Или же это — профессиональный сленг, и пусть его?

> Даже если и будете корчится от боли ― обычно это только первые 2-3
> сеанса, потом привыкается ― если, конечно, у Вас не сильно заниженный
> болевой порог. Simona, 2005.02. 07 02: 57. Есть такой крем, ЭМЛА, он
> обезбаливает. Exbi [Красота, здоровье, отдых: Красота (форум) (2005)]

Answer (score 3):

Правильно только *обезб**о**ливающее.*

> Обезболивающее — существительное пишется только через букву «о» в корне слова «бол-», написание зафиксировано во всех орфографических словарях русского языка. При произношении зачастую слышится буква «а», однако написание этого слова не относится к правилам чередования гласных «о-а» в корне.
>
> https://kak-pravilno.net/obezbolivayushhee-ili-obezbalivayushhee-kak-pravilno/

Comment: Ударный звук отчетлив (к несчастью для этого слова). Но если даже слышится, то почему? Так пишут, потому что слышат... и замыкают круг?

Comment: Как сказано в «Капитанской дочке», не всё то ври, что знаешь — и что слышишь :)

Answer (score 2):

Правильно говорить и писать через «о».

Проверить можно словом «боль».

Поскольку «о» в «обезбо́ливающий» под ударением, тут не должно возникать аканья и звук «о» не должен переходить в «а» в корне.

> **Обезбо́ливающий**, ая, ее (мед.). 1. *Прич. действ. наст. вр. от*
> обезболивать. 2. Применяемый, служащий для обезболивания.
> *Обезболивающие средства.*
>
> *[Толковый словарь Ушакова Д. Н.]*

Транскрипция слова:

> **[аб'избол'ивай'ущ'ий'э]**
>
> *[[razborslova.ru](https://razborslova.ru/%D0%9E/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5)]*

---

Скорей всего, ошибочное произношение возникает из-за того, что в большом количестве однокоренных слов наблюдается аканье: «болеть» [бал’эт'], «больной» [бал’ной], «болезнь» [бал’эз’н'], «заболевание» [забал'иван'ийэ], «больничный» [бал'н'ич'ный] и т. п. — по сходству с этими словами также ошибочно произносят «обезболивающий» через [а].

А из неправильного произношения возникает неправильное написание.

---

**Дополнение**

> При образовании видовой пары у некоторых глаголов в современном
> русском языке наблюдается чередование о – а в корне. Поэтому проверять
> гласную в корне глагола СВ нельзя глаголом НСВ с суффиксами
> -ИВА-/-ЫВА-. Чередование гласных порождает ошибки в образовании глаголов НСВ от производящего глагола СВ, в котором гласная в корне
> под ударением: ***боль — обезболить — обезболивать (обезбаливать —
> ошибка)***.
>
> Действующее правило:
>
> 1. Если в глаголе совершенного вида ударение падает не на корневой гласный **о**, то в парном глаголе несовершенного вида вместо **о**
>    появляется **а**. Это правило в настоящее время в литературном языке
>    не знает исключений: *вЫ**смотр**еть – вы**смАтр**ивать*, корни
>    «смотр» и «сматр»; *за**тормоз**Ить – за**тормАж**ивать*, корни
>    «тормоз» и «тормаж».
> 2. **Если же корневой гласный в глаголе совершенного вида находится под ударением, чередования в несовершенном виде происходить не должно,
>    например: *обезбОлить – обезбОливать*, *уполномОчить –
>    уполномОчивать***. (но тенденция к замене -о- на -а- охватила почти
>    всю эту группу глаголов. В ряде случаев глаголы, у которых еще в
>    начале ХХ в. зарегистрированы формы с -о-, теперь употребляются только
>    с -а-) Под влиянием тенденции к замене о на а ряд слов пишется с
>    буквой а, хоть корень и находится под ударением, например:
>    облагорОдить – облагорАживать (сравните корни!); заморОзить –
>    заморАживать (сравните корни!). Эти слова  – исключения из правила 2,
>    их достаточно много.
>    ...
>    *[[grammatika-rus.ru](https://grammatika-rus.ru/cheredovanie-o-a-v-korne-glagola-na-iva-yva/)]*

Поскольку в глаголе совершенного вида «обезбо́лить» ударение падает на корневой гласный «о» чередования происходить не должно и глагол несовершенного вида будет — «обезбо́ливать», откуда причастие «обезбо́ливающий».

Точно так же в глаголе совершенного вида «просро́чить» ударение падает на корневой гласный «о», поэтому глагол несовершенного вида  — «просро́чивать».

В приведённом правиле сказано, что

> ...тенденция к замене -о- на -а- охватила почти всю эту группу
> глаголов. В ряде случаев глаголы, у которых еще в начале ХХ в.
> зарегистрированы формы с -о-, теперь употребляются только
> с -а-) Под влиянием тенденции к замене о на а ряд слов пишется с
> буквой а, хоть корень и находится под ударением...
>
> *[[grammatika-rus.ru](https://grammatika-rus.ru/cheredovanie-o-a-v-korne-glagola-na-iva-yva/)]*

Возможно, под влиянием именно этой тенденции стали говорить и писать «обезб**а**ливающий», но в отличие от других подобных слов такое произношение и написание пока что не вошло в исключения. Может, потому, что это всё-таки медицинский термин и здесь важна точность, в том числе в соблюдении орфографических правил.

Comment: Нарисую такую цепь: болеутоляющее-обезболевающее-обезбалевающее-обезбаливающее-обезбалевать. Предположу, что не от произношения, а от «грамотности письма»: ведь перед суффиксом -ива- должна всегда быть А. Хотя немногие станут такое утверждать в отношении Просрочивать.

Comment: @shampar Возможно, вы правы, что тут влияет суффикс -ива-. А есть где-то такое правило? «Узако́нивать» тоже может показаться, что надо произносить через [а], хотя «зако́н».

Comment: :) Случай, после которого у меня навсегда пропала охота менять «о» на «а» в «просроченном» (и не только там): в автобусе я краем уха слушал разговор двух бабушек, — речь шла об уличных киосках, где тогда в числе прочего продавали всякие завозные вкусняшки. И вдруг я слышу: «...и наши дураки на них накинулись. А они же у них все ПРОСРАЧЕННЫЕ!»

Comment: Eagle То ли правило, то ли установка... Школьные годы, чудесные.

Comment: @shampar Я нашёл правило и дополнил ответ. Прочитайте «Дополнение», пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо, материал полезный, но с опечатками, пропусками и без ссылок. Будем искать такой же, только...

Comment: @shampar Где именно опечатки и пропуски? Ответ правильный или нет? Причём тут опечатки и пропуски. Пропуски чего?

Comment: @shampar Пропуски чего вы увидели? Какие опечатки вы видите, и насколько существенно они влияют на истинность?

Comment: Я обо всём материале, не о том фрагменте, что приводите здесь. Присмотритесь, и увидите.